# JQuery basic text replacement on click/change using .parent() and .closest()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this dropdown styled with ul and I need to replace the heading with the very first content inside the `<span class="parent">some text</span>`

The `<ul>` contains different sections with each section different headings. Such as locations, provinces, languages etc.

I have figured out how to do this, but each time it only grabs the first heading even if the heading of the chosen option changes.

So for example if I select something from let's say ***Provinces***, the heading of my label doesn't change to ***Provinces*** but it stays on ***Country.***

What am I doing wrong here?

**Screenshot**

[image: Screenshot of the dropdown]

```js
/* Destination selection */
$('.field-destination').each(function() {
  var parent = $(this);

  var dropdown_menu = $('.dropdown-menu', parent);

  $('li', dropdown_menu).on('click', function() {
    $('.destination', parent).text($(this).find('span').text());

    //$('label', parent).text($(this).closest('.parent_li').find('span.parent').text());
    $('label', parent).text($(this).parent().find('.parent_li').closest('li').find('.parent').first().text());

    $('input[name="location_name"]', parent).val($(this).find('span').text());
    $('input[name="location_id"]', parent).val($(this).data('value'));

    if (window.matchMedia('(max-width: 767px)').matches) {
      $('label', parent).hide();
      $('.render', parent).show();
    }
    dropdown_menu.slideUp(50);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group form-extra-field dropdown clearfix field-destination has-icon">
<i class="input-icon field-icon fa"></i>
<div class="dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" id="dropdown-destination">
    <label>Locatie</label>
    <div class="render">
        <span class="destination">Kies een plaats</span>
    </div>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="location_name" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="location_id" value="">
<ul aria-labelledby="dropdown-destination" class="dropdown-menu" tabindex="1">
  <li class="item parent_li" data-country="" data-value=""><span class="parent">Country</span></li>
  <li class="item" data-country="" data-value=""><i class="input-icon field-icon fa"></i><span class="lv2">City</span></li>
  ...
  <li class="item parent_li" data-country="" data-value=""><span class="parent">Provinces</span></li>
  <li class="item" data-country="" data-value=""><i class="input-icon field-icon fa"></i><span class="lv2">Province</span></li>
  ...
  <li class="item parent_li" data-country="" data-value=""><span class="parent">Languages</span></li>
  <li class="item" data-country="" data-value=""><i class="input-icon field-icon fa"></i><span class="lv2">language</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Show the HTML and what you tried

Comment: You are going to need to post your HTML, otherwise the question is going to be closed as no one will be able to assist you.

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for your quick response. I appreciate your help!
I just updated my question with what i already have.

Comment: I see that you added some code but not enough to get a working demo. For example, no where in your HTML is there `field-destination` Try adding enough HTML so that members can get a working demo to work on, otherwise its just a guessing game that won't help anyone help you.